# .NET application to edit SQLite database/file

Tags: .net, sqlite, driver

I'm designing an app in .NET which will enable me to click a button, and in turn, an SQLite file/database will be automatically edited (with a basic query). In order to do this do I need to implement a driver for SQLite, into my application, which will allow it to read the database file? Any help is appreciated, I'm a complete novice.

I've looked at the possibility of using ADO.NET and dbExpress thus far.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to download the SQLite ADO.Net provider from [this site](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)
Then you can follow the general guidelines for ADO.NET using the appropriate classes for SQLite

For more specific questions refer to the FAQ pages on the same site

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement the driver yourself, there are plenty of SQLite drivers for .NET out there already.

A couple of them

- [SQLite ADO.NET provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)
- [Praeclarum's sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)
- [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)